# Аннотация типов в классе

Tags: python, типизация

Как аннотировать переменные объекта класса?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, x: int) -> None:
         self.__x = x #?
```

Comment: Нет необходимости это делать, тип для `self.__x` выведется автоматически из `x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример из `PEP 526 – Syntax for Variable Annotations`, раздел ["Class and instance variable annotations"](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations)

```
class BasicStarship:
    captain: str = 'Picard'               # instance variable with default
    damage: int                           # instance variable without default
    stats: ClassVar[Dict[str, int]] = {}  # class variable
```

Тут `captain` и `damage` - объявлены с аннотациями для атрибутов объекта (instance), третий вариант - с аннотацией для переменной класса. Правда, у `captain` значение по умолчанию делает этот атрибут переменной класса. Но в принципе инициализация объектами неизменяемых типов вполне допустима (первое переписваивание атрибута у объекта перекроет значение атрибута класса). С изменяемыми типами (например, списками) нужно быть осторожнее.

Таким образом, нужно объявить тип вашего поля на верхнем уровне класса:

```
class Node:
    __x: int
    
    def __init__(self, x: int) -> None:
        self.__x = x
```

Если попытаться присвоить значение другого типа, при проверке с помощью mypy выведется ошибка:

```
class Node:
    __x: int
    
    def __init__(self, x: float) -> None:
        self.__x = x
```

```
❯ mypy test.py
test.py:5: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "float", variable has type "int")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

PyCharm также подсветит проблему:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На верхнем уровне — это уже атрибут класса. Можно и прямо в конструкторе: `self.__x: int = x`

Comment: @insolor а это не статистическая переменная?

Comment: @nomnoms12 если туда ничего не присвоено, это не будет атрибутом класса (ни атрибут класса, ни атрибут объекта не будет создан), а будет просто декларацией.

Comment: @RobertHovert нет, там не будет никакой "статической переменной" (атрибута класса), ни атрибута объекта, пока вы туда ничего не присвоите. Это только декларация. Если присвоите через `self.__x`, то будет атрибут объекта (не класса).

Comment: @nomnoms12 более того, чтобы это считалось атрибутом класса, нужно оборачивать аннотацию в ClassVar: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ClassVar

Comment: @insolor Спасибо! Не знал о таком)